# Challenge - Lucas number infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

The challenge: Find the exact value of

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{L_{n}L_{n+2}}$$

Where $L_{n}$ is the $n$-th Lucas number - that is, $L_{0}=2,L_{1}=1$ and $L_{n}=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}$.

Comment: Wait a minute – you posted this, ran into some flak, deleted it – and then posted it again?

Comment: Had some serious improvements to make, Gerry. It's okay to post and answer your own question, but people disliked the way I did it the other time.

Answer (score 4):

Since $$\frac{1}{L_n L_{n+2}} = \frac{1}{L_n L_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{L_{n+1}L_{n+2}}$$ the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{L_n L_{n+2}} $$ is telescoping. Then

$$\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{L_n L_{n+2}} = \frac{1}{L_0 L_1} - \frac{1}{L_{m+1}L_{m+2}}$$

Taking limits we get $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{L_n L_{n+2}} = \frac{1}{L_0 L_1} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $L_{n}\geq f_{n}$ (the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci  number) for all integers $n$ and

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f_{n}f_{n+2}}=1$$

The sum clearly converges.

We observe the first few partial sums:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{1}{L_{n}L_{n+2}}=S_{k}$$

$S_{0}=1/6, S_{1}=5/12, S_{2}=13/28, S_{3}=75/154$

We conjecture that $S_{k}=1/2-\frac{1}{L_{k+1}L_{k+2}}$.

Base case: $k=0$

$S_{0}=\frac{1}{6},1/2-\frac{1}{L_{1}L_{2}}$

Let $q$ be a non-negative integer satisfying $S_{q}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{L_{q+1}L_{q+2}}$

Substitute $k=q+1$

$$\frac{1}{L_{0}L_{2}}+\frac{1}{L_{1}L_{3}}+\frac{1}{L_{2}L_{4}}+...+\frac{1}{L_{q}L_{q+2}}+\frac{1}{L_{q+1}L_{q+3}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{L_{q+1}L_{q+2}}+\frac{1}{L_{q+1}L_{q+3}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{L_{q+2}-L_{q+3}}{L_{q+1}L_{q+2}L_{q+3}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{L_{q+2}-L_{q+2}-L_{q+1}}{L_{q+1}L_{q+2}L_{q+3}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{-L_{q+1}}{L_{q+1}L_{q+2}L_{q+3}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{L_{q+2}L_{q+3}}$$

And hence our conjecture holds true for all integers $k\geq0$.

All we have to do now is take the limit as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{L_{n}L_{n+2}}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{L_{k+1}L_{k+2}}$$

Hence our sum converges to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: What on earth is $f_n$?

Comment: The $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number

Comment: You might consider stating that.